# Creating function in Python to check weather a specific coordinate has an instance of a class

Tags: python, iphone, isinstance

We are creating a predator-prey simulation in Python.

Classes Patch (with coordinates self.x and self.y where the animals can be located), and classes Animal and Animals subclasses Fox and Rabbit.

We need to write a function "has_alive_rabbit".

How do we write a function for the code to see, if a given par of coordinates has an instance of these classes? We have tried: but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if isinstance(self.coordinates(),Animal):
    return TRUE
else:
    return FALSE
```

Methods has_alive_fox(self) -> bool, and has_alive_rabbit(self) -> bool, to check if there is a fox or a rabbit alive on this patch.

Comment: how are you specifying that the animals are located at particular coordinates? it's always easier to help if you show all your code

Comment: Thank you for response. The function should work like this: 

if world_grid[WEL_random][NSL_random].has_alive_rabbit() == True:
                continue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.